# Issue with closing client sockets from server side

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, epoll

I am currently working on web server http project. I noticed something with my siege stress test when I stop it with ctrl c.
I am using Epoll for multiplexing.

1. A client socket (let's say fd = 6), for whom I received an EPOLLIN events via epoll returns 0 after a recv.
2. When it happens, I close the client sock (6) considering something went wrong.
3. After this, I met issues with new requests on the socket server (let say fd = 5) related to the previous socket client (6).
4. If I receive a request on it, I will accept the new connection and get a new client sock (let's say 7 but it could be 6 since i closed the previous one).
5. I'll will set and receive an event EPOLLIN on the client sock 7. I will read what's in it and find an old request from siege.
6. I will respond to this request but get a broken_pipe signal when doing the send.
7. The socket server (5) won't be able to receive any other demand.

It looks like it might be related to SIGPIPE, we SIG_IGN it, but it still doesn't work.
It looks like the socket is broken.

Is there anybody with an idea of what is happening ?

I am available to provide any other information I may forgot.

thanks

Comment: Can you provide the source code for a minimum-sized program that reproduces the fault?  It sounds like there's a bug in the code, but without being able to see the code (or better yet, compile it and run it and observe its behavior) it's unlikely that anyone will be able to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Btw I trust you are removing socket fd=6 from your epoll socket-set (via `EPOLL_CTL_DEL`) before closing the socket?  Leaving epoll() trying to use a closed socket will make epoll() unhappy :/

Comment: I thank you for your comments and interest ! So we found the issue and it was coming from EPOLLET. Removing EPOLLET for server socker 5 solve the problem. I am not sure why. You are right next, I will provide more code. Thank you !